# SQL radius search in Wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress, search, geolocation

[image: screen shot database]

I am trying to do a radius search based on geolocations. I have found code to preform this action with the long and lat values only there is no column called longtitude or latitude because of Wordpress.

How can i preform this search or is there an easier way to do a radius search where a user enters a city name and a distance and there is a search on the data if have got in the database?

```
    SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `locator`
WHERE
    SQRT(POW(`center_lat` - 49.843317 , 2) + POW(`center_lng` - 24.026642, 2)) * 100 < `radius`
```

Comment: Looks like you are using the Pythagorean theory to compute the distance. To accurately compute distances on earth try the Haversine formula which uses spherical geometry to compute distances on a sphere. Google it to find loads of references and possible implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it with the Google maps api and a algorithm to get the distance.

1. Getting the longitude and latitude with the Google api
2. Getting the longitude and latitude of all the posts
3. Comparing both with the code found on this site http://snipplr.com/view/2531/calculate-the-distance-between-two-coordinates-latitude-longitude/ to get the distance
4. Adding the id's of the posts within the search to an array and showing them

Comment: I looked at that PHP function and it is in fact the Haversine forumla.